# What is the Biblical basis that God does not punish disobedient Christians beyond the immediate natural consequences?

Tags: biblical-basis, forgiveness, righteousness, punishment

Suppose that a person is faithful and counted among those in Christ, and the person is disobedient in some manner.

What is the biblical basis that God does not intervene to punish this Christian beyond the immediate natural consequences of their actions, because Christ has already borne the punishment of their transgressions?

Comment: Is this meant to be the counter-point to your [other question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/32539/20)?

Comment: Indeed. I see the questions are already linked.

Comment: What do you mean they are linked?

Comment: @Flimzy On the menu on the right side of the webpage, there is a list of "linked" questions and "related" questions. "Does God punish Christians for disobedience?" appears (alone) in the "linked" list. It's probably because you pasted a link in the comment above.

Comment: Ahh, yes, as you guessed, that's just because I mentioned it in a comment :)

Comment: @Flimzy I don't know, maybe you can help me ask the right question or rewrite this one. I really want to know if there is biblical basis for the notion that God directly intervenes to punish sins here and now. As in, is there immediate punishment from sin, apart from the eternal fate of the wicked?

Comment: There is clearly Biblical evidence that God *has* done so. Whether there's a direct statement that he will continue to do so in present times, I'm not certain. so I think it's a good question.

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks. In that case I'll leave it as is.

Comment: @Andrew I think with your two questions, you will likely gain a better understanding and be able to make a personal decision about the Truth of the matter.

Comment: It seems that the line between discipline and punishment can be unclear. Both are unpleasant, both can be a response to improper behavior. Punishment has more of a sense of retribution (justice) whereas discipline is directed toward training in righteousness and perhaps removing occasions of sin. If discipline (at least of certain types) is considered punishment despite not being based on retribution, then a different answer would be given than if not.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton, that's a very valuable insight. I think there may be some linguistic difficulties with words like "discipline", "punish", "chastise", "scourge" and the like. I'm going to try to clarify at BH.

Comment: [Is there a difference between "punishment" and "discipline"?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13248/is-there-a-difference-between-punishment-and-discipline)

Answer (score 1):

One example is Ramah, a town which Jeremiah prophetically lamented. The area was a source of great dispute between Judah and Israel. The punishment for the unwritten actions which occurred here were fulfilled in Matthew 2:17-18

> 17 Then was fulfilled that which was spoken by Jeremy the prophet, saying,
>
> 18 In Rama was there a voice heard, lamentation, and weeping, and great mourning, Rachel weeping for her children, and would not be comforted, because they are not.

Comment: I think that this answer is on an interesting path. God forgives, and brings back to Israel those that sinned. The weeping will end. So natural consequences as punishment - then not further punishment but reversal and a rebuilding of the Temple. Nice.